# Difference between a Daemon process and an orphan process?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, daemon, orphan

I am confused with daemon process and orphan process. From what I have learnt:

> **Daemon Process**: "These are special processes that run in background.
>   They are system related process that have no associated terminal.These
>   processes run with   root permissions and usually provide services to
>   processes.Usually parent process will terminates and hence child
>   process will become a daemon process as it wont have any terminal.For
>   daemon process, init process will become a parent process"
>
> **Orphan Process**: "when parent process gets killed before child process terminates, then that process becomes an orphan process. In
>   that case the child processes become orphan and then taken under by
>   the init process."

Is an orphan process a daemon process and vice versa? If not, what is the basic difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One doesn't strictly imply the other:
just think of daemons as **intentionally orphaned processes**.
They are intended to work without a parent, but this doesn't apply to every orphaned process!

> It is sometimes desirable to intentionally orphan a process, usually to allow a long-running job to complete without further user attention, or to start an indefinitely running service or agent; such processes (without an associated session) are known as daemons, particularly if they are indefinitely running

Just think of daemons as "slaves" who does the dirt job: you intentionally put them out of your sight, but not everything that goes out of your sight is intended or specifically wanted ;)

I think Wikipedia, in this case, is good enough to satisfy your dilemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer from Defrag.  I would just like to mention that a daemon does not necessarily run as root. In fact, for security reasons, it is preferable not to run some daemons as root, for example a web server process, or an Database listener process. This limits your exposure if the daemon has a security issue.

Also, users themselves could write programs that run as daemon.